# What skills are required to deal with almost every DC problem?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, education

What skills do you recommend me to learn so that i can deal with almost every DC circuit problem and simplify any combination of resistors regardless how complex is it? Surely there's nothing magical that would solve anything but I'm looking for stuff that would make me more intuitive when dealing with circuits, like when does a current not pass by a branch, short circuits and such.

Current skills gained and are being improved:
- Ohm's law 
- Kirchhoff's 2 laws 
- Superposition principle
- Simplifying combinations in parallel and series

Comment: You listed all the tools already. You just need to do a few hundred more examples, to learn the recognize the best (i.e. quickest) ways to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you combine Kirchhoff's Current Law with Ohm's Law, and knowledge of independent and dependent sources, then you can do (Modified) Nodal Analysis. This will let you solve any linear DC circuit.

If you combine Kirchhoff's Voltage Law with Ohm's Law and knowledge of sources, you can do Mesh and Loop Analysis. This will also let you solve any linear DC circuit.

Either of these methods will let you simplify an arbitrary linear resistor network.

Intuition will only come from solving or working with many circuits, so that you're familiar with many common design patterns in circuits.